# Simplifying a set of points

Tags: c#, geometry, computational-geometry, point, mesh

This is one of those situations where if I knew the name of what I was trying to do, I'd probably be able to research it.

Essentially, I have a set of 2D points (vertices) that are sparse in some areas, and concentrated in others. What I want to do is simplify this set by 'intelligently' removing points from the more concentrated areas, whilst leaving the points in sparse areas. I'd want to do this towards a target, so for example start with 50,000 points and end up with 10,000 (or in the region of 10,000 - it needn't be 100% precise).

I'm sure I've seen a technique for doing this before, but I can't remember what it is for the life of me! Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't know what this operation is called (if it has a name) but I think [cluster analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis) will be a necessary step, and likely the hardest part, so I would focus on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something you could try, would be to evaluate each node by totalling the distances from nodes (probably all nodes within a certain distance) and if it is above a certain threshold, remove the node closest to it. If you do this for all nodes, you should end up with a more sparse graph.

Comment: This is the closest to what I ended up doing, and the results were good... but very slow to compute! In the end I ended up loading all of the points in, and for each one storing a list of points within a certain radius. I then iteratively searched for the point with the most neighbours and removed it until all of the nodes didn't have any neignbours left.

Comment: It's called [Ramer–Douglas–Peucker algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm)

Answer (score 2):

Below is some psuedo code (since I do not know your preferred language) for reducing a set of points to a single point per grid paritition. You give it the set of points and the number of partitions along any axis. The code will first walk through the points to find the max/min endpoints to form a bounding box. It will then split the bounding box into the number of partitions along the X and Y axis.

The code will then go through each grid partition and check the array of points for being in the grid. IF the point is in the grid, it will keep the first match and remove the remaining points. Have fun converting the code or changing the criteria to keep a point.

```
function ReduceGrid( array points, int npartitions )
{
    int max_x = 0, max_y = 0;
    int min_x = MAX_INT, min_y = MAX_INT

    // Find the bounding box of the points
    foreach point in points
    {
        if ( point.X > max_x )
            max_x = point.X;
        if ( point.Y < min_x )
            min_x = point.X;
        if ( point.Y > max_y )
            max_y = point.Y;
        if ( point.Y < min_y )
            min_y = point.Y;
    }

    // Get the X and Y axis lengths of the paritions
    float partition_length_x =  ( ( float ) ( max_x - min_x ) ) / npartitions;
    float partition_length_y =  ( ( float ) ( max_y - min_y ) ) / npartitions;

    // Reduce the points to one in each grid partition
    for ( int n = 0; n < npartitions; n++ )
    {
        // Get the boundary of this grid paritition
        int min_X = min_x + ( n * partition_length_x );
        int min_Y = min_y + ( n * partition_length_y );
        int max_X = min_x + ( ( n + 1 ) * partition_length_x );
        int max_Y = min_y + ( ( n + 1 ) * partition_length_y );

        boolean reduce = false; // set to true after finding the first point in the paritition
        foreach point in points
        {
            // the point is in the grid parition
            if ( point.X >= min_x && point.X < max_x &&
                 point.Y >= min_y && point.X < max_y )
            {
                // first point found
                if ( false == reduce )
                    reduce = true;
                else
                    points.Remove( point ); // remove the point from the list
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Andrew, Co-Founder of OpenGeoCode.Org

Comment: I think this is the fastest and simplest method for realtime operation.

Answer (score 0):

I've heard this concept called `decimation`.

The simplest version you would be looking for is "remove every 4 out of 5 points", and hope that your sparse areas will have enough data to survive the ordeal.  This will naturally take more points from the dense areas, (it takes the same percentage from each area, but the more dense areas will obviously have more points to be taken).

Beyond that, you'd need to give more detail.  If you can programmatically find the sparse areas, you can choose to ignore them from your decimation, or take no more than a certain amount.  It could be as simple as "while you're decimating, if the area has <= *x* number left, look for the next area."

Answer (score 0):

You could create a box around the data set, and then divide the box into a grid.  Then for each area of the grid, sum the number of points in it.  Randomly remove points from the most dense area until it has as many points left as the second most dense area and then re-process the grid.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid computing pairwise distances, you can use a [quadtree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) and choose a depth cut-off to get about 10,000 or so nodes from the tree. For the nodes that are subtrees (representing a cluster of points), choose any point in the subtree. See this [Berkeley lecture notes](http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/~demmel/cs267/lecture26/lecture26.html) mentioning using quadtree to collapse clusters of points in a physics simulation.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the generic name of this technique is "Mesh simplification" (see for example http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Surface_mesh_simplification/index.html). You create a Delaunay triangulation out of your points and then iteratively collapse smallest edges until you reach either the required number of vertices or the minimal edge length in the triangulation.

I believe it will be fun for you to come up with arguments why it is natural to use triangulation here and why it's natural for that triangulation to be Delaunay.